# How do I find partial duplicate on first element of a delimited string?

Tags: c#, arrays, split, duplicates, partial

I have a pipe delimited text file that I read into a string array.  The text file will have 2 elements, and the first element could possibly have one or more duplicates.  If there are any duplicates, I want to concatenate the values into 1.

**Example Text File:**

```
ABC|111
DEF|222
GHI|333
ABC|444
JKL|555
ABC|666
```

In this example, "ABC" is duplicated 3 times.  I would like to concatenate the values into a single line separated with a '~' sign.

**New string array values:**

```
ABC|111~444~666
DEF|222
GHI|333
JKL|555
```

The order of the list is not important.  I know how to find duplicate values of an *entire* line using .Distinct(), but I am not sure how to do this with only the first element of the string array.  I would provide some code of my attempt, but I honestly have no idea how to even begin to achieve the desired results.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks.

(Apologies if this post is duplicated.  I had to refresh the page.)

**Edit**
The text file can contain anywhere from 10,000 - 100,000 values.

Comment: You can use `.Split()` to split the string on a delimiter and then compare just part of the string. I suggest that you familiarize yourself with the MSDN documentation in order so that you can find functions which are helpful for your situation.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks!  I did try to use `.Split()` to split the elements, but I did not know how to retain the 2nd element with its respective 1st element, while searching for duplicates with the 1st element.

Comment: Solving programming problems like this often means stepping away from the computer and figuring out the necessary steps before translating those steps into code. I often like to use pen and paper to write these out in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick one that can perhaps get you started:

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> unDupe = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.Length; i++)
{
    string[] split = yourArray[i].Split('|');
    if (unDupe.ContainsKey(split[0]))
    {
        unDupe[split[0]].Add(split[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        unDupe.Add(split[0], new List<string>() { split[1] });
    }
}

List<string> undupinated = new List<string>();

foreach (var keyValuePair in unDupe)
{
    undupinated.Add(string.Concat(keyValuePair.Key, "|", string.Join("~", keyValuePair.Value)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @SharpNip.  This was very helpful to get me going.  Everything worked.  The only thing I had to add was the "|" to retain the original delimiter.

`undupinated.Add(string.Concat(keyValuePair.Key, "|", string.Join("~", keyValuePair.Value)));`

Comment: @Jayarikahs Woops, sorry 'bout that. I'll edit my answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

Say for example you had parsed your input file's rows into an enumerable list of objects with `Key` (eg ABC) and `Value` (eg 111) you could sim[ply use some LINQ `GroupBy` to do what you want:

```
 var result = table.GroupBy(x => x.Key, v => v.Value)
                   .Select( g => g.Key + "|" + String.Join("~",g));
```

Where `table` is your enumerable list.

Live working code: https://rextester.com/HGP1385

---

```
var input = @"ABC|111
DEF|222
GHI|333
ABC|444
JKL|555
ABC|666";

var table = input.Split(new[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => {
      var values = x.Split('|');
        return new { Key = values[0], Value = values[1] };
    });

var result = table.GroupBy(x => x.Key, v => v.Value)
                  .Select( g => g.Key + "|" + String.Join("~",g));

foreach(var r in result)
    Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jamiec.  I went to rextester.com and saw your code in action.  It worked flawlessly.  I am still new to C# and do not know much about LINQ yet, so this code is new to me, but still very helpful and useful.